# 'netcat' not working as expected on Arch, but works on openSUSE Tumbleweed? What's going on?

Tags: arch-linux, opensuse, tcp, netcat

I'm having a bit of trouble utilising `netcat` on Arch, specifically, the GNU version of it.

My situation: I basically made a simple server in Python that can accept multiple clients and send responses. To test for input/output, I made a whole lot of automated testing scripts that would send data through `netcat` to the server and compare the output with what was expected.

On the environment where I developed the server and the test cases, which was openSUSE Tumbleweed, piping text to GNU `netcat` with

```
echo "text" | netcat -w 2 -i 2 ip port > somefile.out
```

worked just as expected - `netcat` sent data to the server, got the response and redirected it to the file. However, on Arch, it almost seems like the `-w` or `-i` flags don't do anything - `netcat` just stays connected indefinitely until I manually have to close the connection. Even when I tried the flags individually, it exhibited similar behaviour.

I tried to use another method with `timeout 2 netcat ...`, which does stop `netcat` from running, but for some reason also stops my entire script and prevents further calls to `netcat` from running at all.

In desperation, I even tried compiling GNU `netcat` from source, and still faced the problem. I tried to search for anyone else having a similar issue on the internet but I wasn't able to find anything that matched my circumstances.

Would anybody know what is happening? I feel like I'm losing my mind. Surely it shouldn't work differently across different distros, unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: there's multiple different versions of netcat. Or at least two, Debian has `netcat-traditional` and `netcat-openbsd`. Check your manpages

Comment: stupid question: does the `ncat` (from the `nmap` package) work any better? (honestly, I think GNU netcat is more or less superseded, it doesn't even support the IP versions of the last 25 years... and it hasn't seen a release in 17 years. Seriously, avoid GNU netcat.)

Comment: Honestly, I think now that I’ve calmed down I realised that the netcat in openSUSE likely wasn’t even GNU netcat at all, but one of the BSD netcats. Apologies, I think I was upset and wasn’t thinking straight when I wrote the question, I’ll double check tomorrow however.

Comment: hmm, so that's what, four different ones? The two I mentioned on Debian seem to be based off some single source (by someone called Hobbit). Neither mentions GNU, so that'd would be a third one, even if badly outdated. And the Nmap one, would be fourth, though with a slightly different name. The three I looked at (the non-GNU ones) all have `-i` and `-w`, but with slightly different meanings, naturally.